# Alert only after 2 conditions meet in sequences

Tags: pine-script, technical-indicator

I want to make alert after 2 conditions met in sequences. Is it posssible?

`alertcondition(rsi > 50 and dicross)` something like this doesnt work.

`alertcondition(rsi > 50 + dicross)` also doesnt work

Comment: What is `dicross` ?

Comment: adx di plus minus. that just an example